# Type error when attempting to draw multiple rectangular images from list to screen in PyGame

Tags: python, class, pygame, typeerror, draw

I am working on making a simple platform game in PyGame. I made a platform class to create platforms from an image file along with a draw method. I also have a method in the main game class that specifies level and specifies which images to draw.

This is the platform class

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Platform(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, xloc, yloc, imgw, imgh, img):
        self.screen = pt_game.screen

        self.image=pygame.image.load('images',img).convert()
        self.image.convert_alpha()
        self.image.set_colorkey(ALPHA)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = yloc
        self.rect.x = xloc

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen,self.rect)
```

and this is the main class while loop, update screen method, and level check method

```
import sys

import pygame

from settings import Settings
from char import Char
from platform import Platform


class Main:
    """overall class to manage game assets and behavior"""

    def __init__(self):
        """initialise game and create new game resources"""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Platformer")

        self.char = Char(self)

    def run_game(self):
        """start main game loop"""
        while True:
            pygame.time.delay(35)
            #Watch for keyboard and mouse events

            self._check_events()
            self.char.update()
            self._draw_levels()
            self._update_screen()

    def _draw_levels(self, Platform):
        if self.settings.level == 1:
            ground = self.Platform(0, 760, 1200, 40, 'images/ground.png')
            platform1 = self.Platform(600, 800, 200, 50, 'images/Platform.png')
            self.platforms = (ground, platform1)

    def _update_screen(self):
        #reraw the screen for each pass through the loop
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.char.blitme()
        [self.Platform.draw(screen) for platform in self.platforms]


        #make most recently drawn screen visible
        pygame.display.flip()
```

The error I get is `TypeError: _draw_levels() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Platform'`

I assume I haven't called the class properly somewhere but I am not sure where. Any help on why this error is occuring would be much appreciated!

note: this is not the full code

Comment: Well you haven't shown us your `_draw_levels` function call. It takes in `Platform` as arg but you don't even use it in that function unless you have cut-out parts of it. I am assuming because of the capital P in `Platform` that the function requires the `Platform` class as argument, so your function call should be `main_class_instance._draw_levels(Platform)`

Comment: Ah, you're right, I haven't called the '''draw_levels''' function, thank you!

Comment: The signature of the method `_draw_levels` is `def _draw_levels(self, Platform):`. However you call `_draw_levels` without any argument `self._draw_levels()`. The mistake is obvious.

Comment: Thanks! It may be obvious to you but I am still new to this so not so much for me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the method `_draw_levels` is `def _draw_levels(self, Platform):`. However you call `_draw_levels` without any argument `self._draw_levels()`.